# How do I add another check for what session is set when it's already checking for one?

Tags: php, session

I want to know how to make a second "check" on what session is set. I am currently using this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../user/connect.php");
include "getn.php";
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'RBLXDev') {
die('lol failure');
}
?>
```

My current username is `RBLXDev`, but I want to make it check if the current username (stored in a session named username) is something like "waffle_".
I believe how you do the `and` statement in PHP is ||, but I don't know how to add to that code.

Comment: It has no sense! If I understood correctly, you want to check if $_SESSION['username'] != $_SESSION['username']!!! Please clarify your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any [Logical Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) in you `if` statement to perform 2 or more checks -

using or / || -

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'RBLXDev' or $_SESSION['username'] != '...') { }
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'RBLXDev' || $_SESSION['username'] != '...') { }
```

using and / && -

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'RBLXDev' and $_SESSION['username'] != '...') { }
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'RBLXDev' && $_SESSION['username'] != '...') { }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been getting errors because I put the || symbol after the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'RBLXDev' && $_SESSION['username'] != 'waffle_')
```

Please read into [php's logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).